# How to Update if key exists otherwise insert

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Suppose you are given user data with unique user ids. How to implement atomic transactions without race conditions.

-Would you SELECT rows that match, if count > 0 UPDATE, else INSET
or
-Would you UPDATE; if 0 rows affected INSERT

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: `UPSERT` maybe? Still, I rarely see a good case for it. You would need to know the PK before inserting... but how? Using a so-called "natural key"? What's the use case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The operation is called "upsert".  In MySQL, you usually do this with [`insert . . . on duplicate key update`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html):

```
insert into t (cols . . .)
    values ( . . . )
    on duplicate key set col = ?, . . . ;
```